# Lazy loading in react - the component is not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone please explain why my lazy loaded component never loads?

All is see is the message loading... on the screen...and no errors.

Below is my code:

```
import React, { Component, lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import "./App.css";
//const Mycomp = lazy(() => import("./components/myComp"));
const Mycomp = lazy(() => {
  let x = new Promise(
    () => {
      import("./components/myComp");
    },
    e => {
      console.log(e);
    }
  );
  return x;
});

class App extends Component {
  sayHi = () => {
    console.log("supa");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<div> loading...</div>}>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <Mycomp />
            <input type="button" value="sayHi" onClick={this.sayHi} />
          </header>
        </div>
      </Suspense>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is simply for learning purpose.. so please be kind.. I'm not very familiar with react in general....

below is the code for myComp.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Mycomp extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <div>Hi i'm loaded now.</div>;
  }
}

export default Mycomp;
```

Comment: does the component you are trying to import have a default export?

Comment: @ChaimFriedman yes. i aded the code for Mycomp component there..

Comment: Your importing `myComp` component while your component name is `Mycomp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from the react docs.

> React.lazy takes a function that must call a dynamic import(). This
>   must return a Promise which resolves to a module with a default export
>   containing a React component.

Now its subtle, but I think in your case you are returning your own newly created promise which you have assigned to `x`. You did not however specify what this promise resolves to. React needs you to return a promise which resolves to a component with a default export.

I think you can make one small change to your code to get it working.

```
const Mycomp = lazy(() => {
   return import("./components/myComp");
});
```

The dynamic import already returns a promise which resolves to a component with a default export, so I think you wrapping it in your own promise which you are returning is throwing it off.

Here is the example from the react docs.

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));
```

Here is some example code showing how do add a timeout.

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => {
  const x = new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(import("./Child"))
    }, 1500)
  })
  return x;
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <OtherComponent />
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes that will work.. but basically what i was trying to do was to add a setTimeout function so i can load the component only after like 5 seconds ... is that possible?

Comment: Ive never tried that. My guess is that so long as you satisfy the requirements of lazy function, you can do anything. That being said I am curious to try that myself.

Comment: yeah.. i was just playing around with it... but i can't get it to work.. and no error messages to go on.. so ... kinda stuck.. :(

Comment: Booting up a sample project now to try. Can I play with this api in CRA?

Comment: yup thats what i did.

Comment: I edited my answer with what worked for me to add a timeout.

Comment: Why did u pass resolve as an argument there in the promise?